# Number Analisys program in Python, I need to get the numbers by Import Random

Tags: python, random

Instead of asking the user for input values, generate 20 random numbers between 1 & 100.

```
import random
print (random.randint(1,100))
```

Will print a random number between 1 and 100.

The program should store the numbers in a list (using the random number generator) then display the following data:

- List item
- The lowest number in the list
- The highest number in the list
- The total of the numbers in the list
- The average of the numbers in the list

This is what I have. But I honestly don't know how to approach this program using the random number. I have previously created this program to accept input from the user. But now I need to change instead of getting an input, need to get the numbers by using the random number generator in Python.

```
def main():
    import random
    series_list = []

    for x in range(20):
        print("The random number ", x + 1, " : ", end = "")
        rand_number = (random.randrange(1,100))
        number = (input(rand_number))
        series_list.append(number)
        
    lowest = min(series_list)
    highest = max(series_list)
    total = sum(series_list)
    average = total / len(series_list)
    print_values(lowest, highest, total, average)


def print_values(lowest, highest, total, average):
    print("The lowest number in the list is: ", lowest)
    print("The highest number in the list is: ", highest)
    print("Total of the number in the list is: ", total)
    print("Average of the number of the list is: ", average)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply remove the `input` statement, you'll get what you need. Every time you call the `input()` function, it asks the user for some input, which is something you don't need.
Replace your `for` loop with this:

```
      for x in range(20):
        rand_number = random.randint(1,100)
        print("The random number ", x + 1, " : ", rand_number)
        series_list.append(rand_number)
```

So, instead of adding the user input (in your code: `number`) to the list, append the randomly generated number.

Comment: I appreciate it. That's exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks